# how to add opening and closing brackets in the condition using unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have conditions in a file, that has around 10 thousend lines. As shown below.

```
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN 1234534
COLUMN_NAME1  NOT  IN  34252
COLUMN_NAME_2 not in    67496575
COLUMN_NAME NOT in   1234534
foo COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (1234534,453535) rest of the line
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN 1234534,453535
columnsd not in (23123124232,6464777) rest on the line
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN 1234534
COLUMN_NAME  NOT  IN  1234534
fdfsdf COLUMN_NAME not in 1234534
COLUMN_NAME not in   1234534
column NOT IN (6764577,434545)
COLUMN_NAME not in   (1234534)
```

I want to use the sed command to add the brackets after the IN clause. I want to replace the conditions above result in output like below.

```
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (1234534)
COLUMN_NAME1  NOT  IN  (3422)
COLUMN_NAME_2 not in    (67496575)
COLUMN_NAME NOT in   (1234534)
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (1234534,453535) rest of the line
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (1234534,453535)
columnsd not in (23123124232,6464777) rest on the line
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (1234534)
COLUMN_NAME  NOT  IN  (1234534)
fdfsdf COLUMN_NAME not in (1234534)
COLUMN_NAME not in   (1234534)
column NOT IN (6764577,434545)
COLUMN_NAME not in   (1234534)
```

Comment: `sed -i.bak 's/\(\sin\s*\)\([0-9]\+\)/\1(\2)/' filename`

Comment: @SamuelKirschner sir its not working for case COLUMN_NAME NOT IN 1234534 and also could you please give me some link reference so I can learn

Comment: @oguzismail awk also adding () where it is already there like COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ((1234534,453535)) and also after the condition also we have some constant Apologies mixed in question

Comment: @oguzismail I added the new edge cases please check

Comment: Please clarify — are the `[NOT] IN` conditions _always_ numeric? You don't explicitly state that, and you really need to be specific when defining this sort of problem. I think Samuel Kirschner's comments are on-track (but I haven't tested)

Comment: I think you forgot the brackets in the 11th line of the example output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be what you are looking for

```
sed -i .bak 's/\(\sin\s\+\)\([^() ]\+\)/\1(\2)/i' file
```

**Explanation**

`s/regexp/replacement/flags` tries to match input line against `regexp`, and if it manages, replaces the matched part with `replacement`.

1. `regexp` part:

   - `\(\sin\s\+\)` (ERE: `(\sin\s+)`) matches a space followed by `in` plus one or more spaces, and keeps the matched portion in capture group 1,
   - `\([^() ]\+\)` (ERE: `([^() ]+)`) matches a group of non-space, non-parenthesis chars and keeps it in capture group 2,
2. `replacement` part:

   - `\1(\2)` expands up to `<capture group 1>(<capture group 2>)`,
3. `flags` part:

   - `i` makes the matching case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks it works Could you please explain the code or please provide some reference, So I can go through?

Comment: Apologies I am very new in unix could you please explain /\1(\2\)/. Thank you for your Help

Comment: Thank you it helps

Answer (score 2):

Lets take it step by step.

I guess the best rule would be:

- IN (case insensetive) `IN`
- followed by: a number `[0-9]\+`
- optionally followed by multiple (`*`): comma and number `,[0-9]`

This would result in the regex:
`IN[0-9]\+\(,[0-9]\+\)*`

Next step is to add mandatory (`\s`) and optional (`\s*`) whitespace:

```
\sIN\s*[0-9]\+\s*\(,\s*[0-9]\+\s*\)*
```

Now to replace `\sIN\s*` `[0-9]\+\s*\(,\s*[0-9]\+\s*\)*` with `\1(\2)` it you need capture groups.

```
\(\sIN\s*\)\([0-9]\+\s*\(,\s*[0-9]\+\s*\)*\)
```

Now the regex has to go inside `s//\1(\2)/i` (the `i` means case insensitive)

```
s/\(\sIN\s*\)\([0-9]\+\s*\(,\s*[0-9]\+\s*\)*\)/\1(\2)/i
```

And at last we have a shell command, including a backup in case of mistakes.

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(\sIN\s*\)\([0-9]\+\s*\(,\s*[0-9]\+\s*\)*\)/\1(\2)/i' filename
```

I tested it on your example data and the output is:

```
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (1234534)
COLUMN_NAME1  NOT  IN  (34252)
COLUMN_NAME_2 not in    (67496575)
COLUMN_NAME NOT in   (1234534)
foo COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (1234534,453535) rest of the line
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (1234534,453535)
columnsd not in (23123124232,6464777) rest on the line
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (1234534)
COLUMN_NAME  NOT  IN  (1234534)
fdfsdf COLUMN_NAME not in (1234534)
COLUMN_NAME not in   (1234534)
column NOT IN (6764577,434545)
COLUMN_NAME not in   (1234534)
```